# Notice: Undefined variable: content_block1 and content_menu in header.tpl in opencart

Tags: opencart

Notice: Undefined variable: content_block1 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/megashop/catalog/view/theme/so-market/template/common/header.tpl on line 800

Notice: Undefined variable: content_menu in /opt/lampp/htdocs/megashop/catalog/view/theme/so-market/template/common/header.tpl on line 825

How To fix It .

Answer (score 0):

> Try This

it just a Notice 
Go to `admin` -> `setting` -> `setting` -> `Edit Your Store` -> `Server Tab` -> `Display Errors` -> Select `No` and `Save`.

and Refresh Page.

Comment: My Main Menu disapears when I did the same But I wants that my Main Menu should be visible in content_menu and content_block1

Actually I tried to change header.php and header.tpl file that this situation occure Please Help me to Fix it.